# Getting an error while calling mySql proceedure

Tags: java, mysql

I have created a single procedure for update for different table say country & department.
and in procedure i'hve mentioned an input parameter for table name along with other parameter.
But unfortunately i got an error. Here is mySql Procedure:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`satish`@`%` PROCEDURE `p_update_Master_Name`(
IN tbl_Name VARCHAR(35),
IN tbl_column_old_value VARCHAR(35),
IN tbl_column_new_value VARCHAR(35),
IN tbl_user_id INT,
OUT msg INT 
)
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT Name from tbl_name where Name = tbl_column_new_value) then        
SET msg := '1';
-- failed case  

else

UPDATE tbl_name SET Name= tbl_column_value, Modified_Date=now(),       Modified_by=tbl_user_id where Name = tbl_column_old_value;
set msg := '0';
-- success 
END IF;
END
```

Im calling this procedure from java file.

```java
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{ call p_update_Master_Name(?,?,?,?,?)}");
            cs.setString(1, "country");
    cs.setString(2, real);
    cs.setString(3, mod);   
    cs.setInt(4, 01);
    cs.execute();
            cs.registerOutParameter(5, Types.INTEGER);
            int i=cs.getInt(5);
```

but it gives me a mysql.jdbc exception.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'sims.tbl_name' doesn't 
exist
```

Please help me. Thanx in advance

Comment: As far as I can see the variable has been declare as tbl_Name and in your code is tbl_name

Comment: thnks. but somehow it doesn't work. even after changing the tbl_Name to tbl_name. im getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables to define table or column (or any other db object for that matter) names in static SQL queries. They should be literals.

You have to use dynamic SQL to achieve your goal. Read more on the topic [SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Your stored procedure might look like

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p_update_Master_Name
(
    IN tbl_Name VARCHAR(35),
    IN tbl_column_old_value VARCHAR(35),
    IN tbl_column_new_value VARCHAR(35),
    IN tbl_user_id INT,
    OUT msg INT 
)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT (COUNT(*) > 0) INTO @result FROM ', tbl_name, ' WHERE Name = \'', tbl_column_new_value, '\'');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;

    SET msg = @result;

    IF @result = 0 THEN
      SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE ', tbl_name, 
                        ' SET Name = \'', tbl_column_new_value, 
                        '\', Modified_Date = NOW(), Modified_by = ', tbl_user_id, 
                        ' WHERE Name = \'', tbl_column_old_value, ' \'');
      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
      EXECUTE stmt;
    END IF;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec753/2)** demo

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some error with the procedure syntax

wrong one:
 1. SELECT Name from ***tbl_name*** where Name = tbl_column_new_value) then
SET msg := '1'

In the above line of code you didn't set any value to tal_name;

You can refer the below syntax concentrate on INTO in the query:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getDBUSERByUserId(
           p_userid IN DBUSER.USER_ID%TYPE,
           o_username OUT DBUSER.USERNAME%TYPE,
           o_createdby OUT  DBUSER.CREATED_BY%TYPE,
           o_date OUT DBUSER.CREATED_DATE%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN

SELECT USERNAME , CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE
  **INTO** o_username, o_createdby,  o_date 
  FROM  DBUSER WHERE USER_ID = p_userid;

END;